# xsl sum siblings based on node value

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to apply an xsl transformation that sums certain node values based on the value of one of its sibling nodes. Here's my xml pseudo code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<Message>
    <Body>
        <Order>
            <Item>
                <.../>
                <Type>widget</Type>
                <Qty>20</Qty>
                <.../>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <.../>
                <Type>gadget</Type>
                <Qty>10</Qty>
                <.../>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <.../>
                <Type>widget</Type>
                <Qty>5</Qty>
                <.../>
            </Item>
            <Item/>
        </Order>
    </Body>
</Message>
```

The desired result of the the quantity summation for all items of type 'widget' is 25

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/Message/Body/Order/Item/Qty)"/>
```

is yielding 35

My xsl stylesheet details

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
version="2.0"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add predicates to find the nodes that you're interested (i.e. 'widget') only:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/Message/Body/Order/Item[Type = 'widget']/Qty)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Fung, seems I was overcomplicating as usual. maybe this will help someone else.

    <xsl:value-of select="sum(/Message/Body/Order/Item[Type!='gadget']/Qty)"/>

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_examples.asp

Comment: @user1555096 - Depending on your needs, you may want to use `not(Type='gadget')` instead of `Type!='gadget'`. That way you still include `Qty` if the `Item` doesn't have a `Type`. Also +1 to Fung for a good answer.