# xsl sum siblings with different parent based on node value

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

similar to this link [xsl sum siblings based on node value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848008/xsl-sum-siblings-based-on-node-value), I need to apply an xsl transformation that sums certain node values based on the value of one of its sibling nodes, the problem is there are similar nodes that i want to get the sum of but i was not able to figure out the xslt because of varying parents. here is how the xml looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<Message>
<Body>
    <Order>
        <Item1>
            <.../>
            <Type>widget</Type>
            <Qty>20</Qty>
            <.../>
        </Item1>
        <Item>
            <.../>
            <Type>gadget</Type>
            <Qty>10</Qty>
            <.../>
        </Item>
        <Item2>
            <.../>
            <Type>widget</Type>
            <Qty>5</Qty>
            <.../>
        </Item2>
        <Item3>
            <.../>
            <Type>widget</Type>
            <Qty>2</Qty>
            <.../>
        </Item3>
        <Item3>
            <.../>
            <Type>Other</Type>
            <Qty>0</Qty>
            <.../>
        </Item3>
        <Item/>
    </Order>
   </Body>
</Message>
```

I want to be able to group through type widget and get the sum of quantity, my xslt is like this.

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/Message/Body/Order/Item1|Item2|Item3[Type = 'widget'] /Qty)"/>
```

my code does not give me an error but it also does not return anything. I want my output to be like below without hardcoding the types on the xml such as widget, gadget cause that could also change to other types.

Widget Total = 27
Gadget Total = 10

I also would like to exclude including Type with sum equal to 0 from the output.

Thanks!
Raf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current expression is the operator precedence rules - your XPath of

```
/Message/Body/Order/Item1|Item2|Item3[Type = 'widget']/Qty
```

parses as

```
(/Message/Body/Order/Item1)
|
(Item2)
|
(Item3[Type = 'widget']/Qty)
```

Since you've tagged the question as XSLT-2.0, you can use parentheses:

```
/Message/Body/Order/(Item1|Item2|Item3)[Type = 'widget']/Qty
```

Or a wildcard if you don't know all the possible names up-front

```
/Message/Body/Order/*[Type = 'widget']/Qty
```

As for the more general question, this looks like a good job for. `for-each-group`

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/Message/Body/Order/*" group-by="Type">
  <xsl:variable name="totalQty" select="sum(current-group()/Qty)"/>
  <xsl:if test="$totalQty gt 0">
    <item type="{current-grouping-key()}" qty="{$totalQty}"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Hi Ian is there a way not to hardcode the Types that I'm getting? for example i do not want to have to create a path for each types such as /Message/Body/Order/(Item1|Item2|Item3)[Type = 'widget']/Qty, /Message/Body/Order/(Item1|Item2|Item3)[Type = 'gadget']/Qty, i wanted it to be dynamic. Thanks!

Comment: @raf as you're working in XSLT 2.0 you're in luck - it's easy with `for-each-group`

Answer (score 0):

try having these instead:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/Message/Body/Order//Qty[preceding-sibling::Type[.='widget']])"/>

<xsl:value-of select="sum(/Message/Body/Order//Qty[preceding-sibling::Type[.='gadget']])"/>
```

results in `27` and `10` respectively.

**EDIT**

In xslt-2.0, you can use `xsl:for-each-group` as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/Message/Body/Order/*" group-by="Type">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(current-grouping-key(), ': ')"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="sum(current-group()/Qty)"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it outputs:

```
widget: 27
gadget: 10
Other: 0
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Sorry i was not very clear with my question. is there a way not to hard code the type in the xpath?

Comment: you need to use keys, as answered by Tim C.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a `key` here to look up the items. Assuming the items you wish to sum are always children of `order` elements, they key would look like this:

```
 <xsl:key name="item" match="Order/*" use="Type" />
```

Then to sum up the "widget" items, you would do this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('item', 'widget')/Qty)" />
```

And if you wanted to exclude sums with a total of 0 from the output, just use a variable instead, and check that

```
<xsl:variable name="widget" select="sum(key('item', 'widget')/Qty)" />
<xsl:if test="$widget > 0">
    <xsl:text>Widget Total = </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$widget" />
</xsl:if>
```

And if you wanted to avoid hard-coding, one way is to use `xsl:for-each-group` to get the distinct items, for example:

```
  <xsl:for-each-group select="//Order/*" group-by="Type">
    <xsl:variable name="value" select="sum(key('item', Type)/Qty)" />
    <xsl:if test="$value > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="Type" />
        <xsl:text> Total = </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Tim!, the sum could also have a negative value but i get that part. My xml could also have Body1 and Body2 but widget, gadget, and other could also change to other type is there a way to not hard code them? Sorry if this is not in the original question i will update my post. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer to show a possible way. Although I see Ian Roberts has done the same, but better (by using `current-group`, which removes the need for the key).